# Arabic symbols in PHP mail subject

Tags: php, encoding, sendmail, arabic

In one of the projects I need to send a letter in Farsi (Arabic). As for the body of the message, I'm converting the Arabic symbols to ASCII code which works like a charm. The problem is with the subject field. Whatever encoding I try to set I always get question marks instead of the text. Could anybody help me with this, please? Here's my code:

```
$subject = '=?utf-8?B?'.base64_encode(mb_convert_encoding('انصراف از دریافت پیام های اطلاع رسانی', "UTF-8","US-ASCII")).'?=';
```

Thanks.

Comment: I've updated the question with the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

$subject_evernote = mb_encode_mimeheader("العربية");
```

Regards

Comment: With your code I actually did not use base64 encoding but it still did not work.